# How to count in Java the trailing zeros from an Integer? (Ex: 234000 => 3 zeros)

Tags: java, integer

The title is pretty much self explanatory. :)

```
1232 => 0
1231030 => 1
2000 => 3
34444400000 => 5
```

Comment: there are several ways to do this... How would you do it?

Comment: There also this method Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(num)

Comment: @Aeshang `numberOfTrailingZeros` counts zero **bits**, not decimal digits.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it fits into an `int`/`long`, just check if the number modulo 10 is 0 and keep a counter:

```
long x = ...
if (x == 0) {
    return 0;
}
int counter = 0;
while (x % 10 == 0) {
    counter++;
    x /= 10;
}
```

If it's too big to fit in `long`, store it in a `String` and count zeroes from the last char:

```
String s = ...
int counter = 0;
while(counter < s.length() && s.charAt(s.length() - 1 - counter) == '0') {
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: need to add `&& x > 0` to your conditional. otherwise it would go infinite if `x == 0`.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow fixed with a prior validation.

Comment: The second example is pretty compact. I recommend converting to `char` array, then using an enhanced loop to iterate (if legability is a concern): `for(char c : Integer.toString(i).toCharArray())` requires an extra line for the condition, but far more legible. +1 for your example that doesn't require parsing, very nice

Comment: @VinceEmigh some years ago I thought that was an optimal solution, but then I found it is not.

Comment: @VinceEmigh because `toCharArray` has to do a copy of the content of the current `char[]` backed to maintain immutability of the `String`, which is a small performance hit just to gain *shorter readable* code. So if the `String` content should not be modified then I'll work directly with the methods `String` class provide.

Comment: There might be a faster way to infer that by shifting bits, but I have no clue.

Comment: That makes sense; Strings are immutable, so a copy would be needed to ensure immutability of the previous String. Thanks! :)

Comment: @chrisapotek I found such method implemented in C/C++ but declares the number as `unsigned` which is not supported in Java. Java 8 supports unsigned through `Integer` and `Long` but doesn't provide the feature you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Integer class has an inbuilt function to count the trailing zeros.
[javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfTrailingZeros(int))

```
int trailingZeroes = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(int i);
```

Comment: jshell> Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(1232);
$1 ==> 4

Comment: This method seems to calculate number of trailing zeros in base 2, _not_ in base 10!

Answer (score 4):

Three lines:

```
int zeroes = 0
while(num%10 == 0 && num != 0) {
  zeroes++;
  num /= 10;
}
```

This uses the modulus operator. As long as we can divide by ten without remainder, increment the counter.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution using Java 8 Streams:

```
int trailingZeros = String.valueOf(number).chars()
        .reduce(0, (count, ch) -> (ch == '0') ? count + 1 : 0);
```

This transforms the number to an IntStream. This stream is then reduced using a lambda which resets a counter each time a non-zero char comes up.

Comment: This reduction function violates the associativity constraint. As a consequence, it will break with parallel streams. But even if it happens to produce the intended result in a sequential evaluation, it must be considered a wrong use of the API.

Answer (score 2):

You could always just use a regular expression:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(0+)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(String.valueOf(123140000));
Integer trailingZeroes = 0;
if (matcher.find()) {
    trailingZeroes = matcher.group(1).length();
} 
System.out.println(trailingZeroes);
```

Comment: +1 though you forgot to handle the case of no trailing zeros ;)

Comment: You could have said `(0*)` and then you wouldn't need a separate test, I think.

Comment: Using `matcher.end(1) - matcher.start(1)` might be more efficient than `matcher.group(1).length()`, as it avoids creating a `String`, just for extracting its length. Further, there’s no reason to box the result into an `Integer`; just using `int` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Not tried this code but this should work.

```
int counterForZeros=0;
for(long i=10;true;)
{
    if(num%i==0)
    {
        counterForZeros++;
        i*=10;
    }
    else 
    {
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println("Number of zeros in "+num+" is "+counterForZeros);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can turn the `int` to a `String` and iterate in reverse, counting the zeros until you find a char that is not zero:

```
int countZeros(int x){
    String a = Integer.toString(x);
    int numOfZeros = 0;
    for(int i = a.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (a.charAt(i) != '0') break;
        else numOfZeros ++;

    return numOfZeros;          
}
```

Testing with : 
`System.out.println(countZeros(25000));` will print `3` 
`System.out.println(countZeros(25));` will print `0`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this is a contest to see who can do it in the fewest lines:

```
trailingZeroes = String.valueOf(num).length() - String.valueOf(num).replaceAll("0*$","").length();
```