# Count occurrence of leading zeros before a number using pattern

Tags: java, regex

A very simple question. I need to get the number of trailing zeros before the occurence of first number i.e:

```
0000450 => 4
00632000670 => 2
77830 => 0
```

Here is what I have tried already, thanks to [already answerd question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773422/how-to-count-in-java-the-trailing-zeros-from-an-integer-ex-234000-3-zeros):

```
public static Integer trailingZeros(String s){
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(0+)$");
    Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(String.valueOf(s));
    Integer trailingZeroes = 0;
    if (matcher.find()) {
        trailingZeroes = matcher.group(1).length();
    }
    return trailingZeroes;
}
```

Comment: use `(0*)\\d+` and use the group to find length

Comment: Why is the method called `trailingZeros` when you want it to count **leading** zeros?

Comment: What should it return for `0000`? 4? --- What should it return for `000xyz`? 3?

Comment: Why is the `trailingZeroes` variable an `Integer`? It should be an `int`.

Comment: it was originally coded in apex.. hence the use of Integer

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your issue? Please consider accepting the one that works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to count initial zeros, you may even use a non-regex solution like

```
public static int countInitialZeros(String haystack) {
    for (int i=0; i < haystack.length(); i++)
    {
        if (haystack.charAt(i) != '0') { // if current char is not 0
            return i;                    // return the index, it the count
        }
    }
    return haystack.length();          // If we get here, the whole string is made of zeros
}
```

See the [online Java demo](http://ideone.com/e1jWQP).

Test:

```
System.out.println(countInitialZeros("0005606")); // => 3
System.out.println(countInitialZeros("005606"));  // => 2
System.out.println(countInitialZeros("05606"));   // => 1
System.out.println(countInitialZeros("5606"));    // => 0
System.out.println(countInitialZeros("0000"));    // => 4
```

NOTE: if you really need to make sure the string only consists of digits, you may use `s.matches("\\d+")` before counting the zeros.

Here is a regex approach that both makes sure the string is made of digits and returns the count of initial zeros:

```
public static int countInitialZeros(String haystack) {
    return haystack.replaceFirst("^(0*)[1-9]\\d*$", "$1").length();
}
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/hiyNFQ). The `^(0*)[1-9]\\d*$` matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(0*)` - Group 1: zero or more `0`s
- `[1-9]` - a digit from `1` to `9`
- `\\d*` - zero or more digits
- `$` - the end of string.

And if you want to return a `-1` for a string that does not only consist of digits you might use

```
public static int countInitialZeros(String haystack) {
    return haystack.matches("\\d+") ? haystack.replaceFirst("^(0*)[1-9]\\d*$", "$1").length() : -1;
}
```

See [this Java demo](http://ideone.com/Nrm86I). `countInitialZeros("abc")` returns `-1`.

Comment: You don't need the `count` variable, as it always has the same value as `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Issue : `(0+)$` here it mean capture atlease one or more zeros, then end of string mean it will find match only of `0` or `00000` more zeros , everything else will not be matched

- `(^0*)\\d*` capture `^` starting with

  - 0*   : zero or more occurrence of `0`
- \d* : zero or more digits

---

```
public static Integer trailingZeros(String s){
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(^0*)\\d*");
        //                              ^   ^ group 1
        Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(String.valueOf("77830"));
        matcher.find()
    return matcher.group(1).length();
    //     simply return the length 
    // will return zero in case of no match found 
}
```