# How to count the number of trailing zeroes in an integer using Java 8 Stream/Lambda?

Tags: java, algorithm, lambda, java-8, java-stream

How to count the number of trailing zeroes in an integer using Java 8 Stream/Lambda?

Basically the logic should be: keep the integer dividing by `10` as long as the remainder is `0` (the quotient will be supplied to the next division) and count the occurrence(s).

e.g.

`12300 % 10 == 0` `true`

`1230 % 10 == 0` `true`

`123 % 10 == 0` `false`

Answer: `2`

**Note:** I prefer not to involve String here :-)

Comment: There is a method for that in `Integer` class...

Comment: @Eugene, I believe the `Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros` method works on binary level rather than decimal as requested by the OP. Or did you mean some other method?

Comment: @Saikat, I believe Java8 streams are not designed for such usage scenarios. Do you have any particular reason to implement that using `Stream` rather than a trivial `for` loop?

Comment: I was just wondering if it's possible :) @SergGr `Number.numberOfTrailingZeros` is a great revelation ;) All I need to do is to convert it in decimal (as you have rightly pointed out)

Comment: I mean [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49161539/8534008) is a `Stream` version, but it involves a conversion to a `String`

Comment: @GBlodgett quite interesting answer using String, thanks!

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? If not, why not?

Comment: @GBlodgett but it must be considered [a wrong solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773422/how-to-count-in-java-the-trailing-zeros-from-an-integer-ex-234000-3-zeros/49161539#comment95686820_49161539).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a purely hypothetical question, here is a purely hypothetical answer of how you can do it:

```
static int countZeroes(int value) {
    if(value == 0) // we need to handle this case explicitly
        return 1; 
    IntStream s = IntStream.iterate(value, v -> v / 10);
    return (int) takeWhile(s, v -> v > 0 && v % 10 == 0)
            .count();

}
```

It uses a helper function `takeWhile` that is available in Java 9 but not in Java 8 so has to be emulated like this:

```
// In Java 9 there is a standard takeWhile
// https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-
// but in Java 8 I have to emulate it
static IntStream takeWhile(IntStream s, final IntPredicate pr) {
    final Spliterator.OfInt origSp = s.spliterator();

    Spliterator.OfInt filtered = new Spliterators.AbstractIntSpliterator(origSp.estimateSize(), 0) {
        boolean lastPredicate = true;

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(final IntConsumer action) {
            if (!lastPredicate)
                return false;

            origSp.tryAdvance((int v) -> {
                lastPredicate = pr.test(v);
                if (lastPredicate) {
                    action.accept(v);
                }
            });
            return lastPredicate;
        }
    };

    return StreamSupport.intStream(filtered, false);
}
```

The idea is that

```
IntStream.iterate(value, v1 -> v1 / 10).takeWhile(v -> v > 0)
```

should generate a stream of cutting digits at the end one by one and then you can apply `takeWhile(v -> v % 10 == 0).count()` to count the number of zeros and finally you can merge those two `takeWhile`s into one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:-

```
private static int countTrailingZeroes(int n) {
    int length = n == 0 ? 1 : (int) (Math.log10(n) + 1); //number of digits in n
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, length)
            .map(i -> length - i)           //reverse stream
            .map(o -> (int) Math.pow(10, o))
            .filter(o -> n % o == 0)
            .boxed()
            .findFirst()
            .map(i -> (int) Math.log10(i))  //number of digits minus 1
            .orElse(0);
}
```

**@Holger's edit:**

```
private static int countTrailingZeroes(int n) {
    int length = n == 0 ? 1 : (int) (Math.log10(n) + 1); //number of digits in n
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, length)
            .map(i -> length - i)           //reverse stream
            .filter(o -> n % (int) Math.pow(10, o) == 0)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(0);
}
```

Comment: When you replace `.map(o -> (int) Math.pow(10, o)) .filter(o -> n % o == 0)` with a single `.filter(o -> n % (int) Math.pow(10, o) == 0)` step, you don’t need the `.map(i -> (int) Math.log10(i))` at the end. Which in turn eliminates the need for `.boxed()`.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you don't have `Java9`'s `takeWhile` method, this can also do the trick:

```
static final int[] POWERS_OF_10 = { 1000000000, 100000000, 10000000,
        1000000, 100000, 10000, 1000, 100, 10 };

static int trailingZeros(int number) {
    return Arrays.stream(POWERS_OF_10)      // reversed stream of of 10^n
                 .map(pow -> number % pow)  // stream of rests
                 .reduce(0, (count, rest) -> (rest == 0) ? count + 1 : 0);
}
```