# How to add an object to existing array if object.values is non empty using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have an Optional object Product. I have to add this object to an existing set if product.locations is non empty

```
Set<Product> s = new HashSet()P:

if(!product.locations().empty()){ // product.locations() returns Collection<Location>
 s.add(product);
}
```

Maybe something like ..

```
p.map(Product::location).isNonEmpty(s.add(p))?
```

How can I achieve this using Java 8 api/map/flatmap functions?

Comment: The question is ambiguous in the sense, that does a `Product` returns a  `Location` or `List<Location>`?

Comment: @Naman From what I understood, `Product` class has a field `List<String> locations`. Also, `product` is of type `Optional<Product>`. If the locations list in this `product` is empty, the OP wants to add this product to the set.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
product.map(Product::getLocations)
        .filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())
        .ifPresent(l -> s.add(product.get()));
```

**@Holger's edit**

```
product.filter(p -> !p.getLocations().isEmpty())
        .ifPresent(s::add);
```

Comment: In the line of code `.ifPresent(l -> s.add(product.get()));`, what's the use of `l` and what does `product.get()` result into?

Comment: @Naman `l` is ignored here. `product` in an Optional, so `product.get()` will give its value.

Comment: So why don’t you use `product.filter(p -> !p.getLocations().isEmpty()).ifPresent(s::add);`? The original `if` statement does already show the logic; there’s no reason to introduce a `map` step.

Comment: @Holger you had corrected this exact mistake in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54431070/1039555), which proves I'll never learn :(